# Return of wrong ASCII code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the following script, when `del` key is pressed it returns `46` instead of `127`, which is the ASCII code of `del` key.

```
function countLength(evt) {
            var inp = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
            alert (inp);
            return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values returned by `event.keyCode` are not ASCII codes. They just indicate which key was pressed on the keyboard. For example pressing `0`-key on the topmost row of the keyboard returns 48, but pressing `0` on numberblock returns 96.

To convert keycodes to ASCII , you have to use some kind of an array containing corresponding values. In this task you have to check all other keys pressed simultaneously, like `shiftKey` and `altKey` to have correct results.

Comment: The first paragraph is correct. However, there is no guaranteed mapping between key codes and character codes: this will vary between keyboard layouts and types. The only event that will give you reliable information about character codes is the `keypress` event, and when using that, you don't have to mess around with checking modifier keys such as Shift or Alt.

Comment: @TimDown That is true (self using scandinavian keyboard), but through `keypress` you can't have all keys pressed (`delete` for example). I was just about to add this issue to my answer, but it seems to be unnecessary, beacause it is in your comment already.

Comment: `keypress` detects everything printable, but it's true that it doesn't fire for non-printable keystrokes in all browsers. For detecting the Delete key I'd use `keydown`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are getting `evt` from becaue it is standalone function. If you are passing it then change:

```
event.keyCode;
```

To:

```
evt.keyCode;
```

Or try changing `evt` in all three cases to `event` or vice versa.

Comment: `<form name="formA" id="formA" action="#" >
   <textarea id="txt" name="txt" onkeydown="return countLength(event)"></textarea>
  </form>`

Comment: Try changing `event` to `evt` in all places and opposite of it for all again if it does not work.

Comment: @sandbox: That's weird then, there might be some other reason not sure though. I would use jQuery to solve it though.